# Cannot find namespace NodeJS when using NodeJS.Timer in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am attempting to use some code I found on https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/289#issuecomment-277143172 to my Ionic project.

When I run the code I get an error `Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'` and the error refers to `touchTimeout: NodeJS.Timer;`

How can I adapt the code below to make the `NodeJS.Timer` line work?

```ts
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[delayDragLift]' })
export class DelayDragLiftDirective {

    dragDelay: number = 200; // milliseconds
    draggable: boolean = false;
    touchTimeout: NodeJS.Timer;

    @HostListener('touchmove', ['$event'])
    // @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
    onMove(e: Event) {
        if (!this.draggable) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            clearTimeout(this.touchTimeout);
        }
    }

    @HostListener('touchstart', ['$event'])
    // @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    onDown(e: Event) {
        this.touchTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.draggable = true;
        }, this.dragDelay);
    }

    @HostListener('touchend', ['$event'])
    // @HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
    onUp(e: Event) {
        clearTimeout(this.touchTimeout);
        this.draggable = false;
    }

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - use correct version of setTimeout (node vs window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802988/typescript-use-correct-version-of-settimeout-node-vs-window)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A quick way to solve this problem is [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6325).

Basically change `setTimeout` and `clearInterval` to `window.setTimeout` and `window.clearInterval`, respectively. For example, your `onDown` becomes:

```
onDown(e: Event) {
    this.touchTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.draggable = true;
    }, this.dragDelay);
}
```

Then, your declaration becomes:

```
this.touchTimeout: number | undefined;
```

Comment: This should be accepted, since you shouldn't include node types into an Angular project which is targeting browsers.

Answer (score 107):

Open `src/tsconfig.app.json`*.

Add `"node"` to the `"types"` array.

Example:

```js
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

*if this file does not exist add the specified part to `tsconfig.json` in root folder.

Answer (score -3):

To me, solve include the **typeRoots** member in **compilerOptions** from tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
         "node_modules/@types"
     ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```