# How to import `NodeJS.Timer` type in react-native

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I want to use the type `NodeJS.Timer` as a type annotation in one of my classes:

```
const interval: NodeJS.Timer = setInterval(this._func, 1000)
```

How can I import this type?
I am using flow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find namespace NodeJS when using NodeJS.Timer in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315304/cannot-find-namespace-nodejs-when-using-nodejs-timer-in-ionic-2)

Comment: Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367655/23118.

Comment: @hlovdal this answer is for typescript, no? Will it work for flow?

Comment: Ah, yes for typescript. Sorry I did not see this was something different.

Answer (score 1):

Flow uses the `IntervalID` type as the return type from the `setInterval`/`setTimeout` functions. You can see the function typedef [here in the core defs](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/a610efd397c8ed8add4c615794b7a84ad8fa4447/lib/core.js#L732).

To use it, just type `interval` with that type:

```
const interval: IntervalID = setInterval(this._func, 1000)
```