# pg-promise in Angular app gives many 'Module not found' errors

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, postgresql, pg-promise

I am including [`pg-promise`](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) in my Angular app to make some queries.

My app is targeting browsers and I am willing to deploying it via `ng build --prod`.

However, when I launch the development server with Angular CLI using `ng serve` I get lots of errors and my app does not work since I imported `pg-promise` with:

```
import * as pgPromise from 'pg-promise';
```

Errors are like `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'XXX' in 'path`.

[image: Errors I am receiving]

I tried to solve with the solutions provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367655/1979665):

> Open src/tsconfig.app.json*.
>
> Add "node" to the "types" array.

, and installing node types via `npm i @types/node`, but nevertheless I am still hitting the same errors.

Finally, lookig at the types declared in the `pg-promise.d.ts` file, I can clearly see there's an error which makes me think is the cause of the problems I am having. VScode is telling me that it `Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.ts(2503)`.

[image: Node.js error in pg-promise.d.ts file]

Any suggestion on how I should include `pg-promise` in my app without all these errors?

Comment: You shouldn't even try bundling `pg-promise` with a web app, it is strictly a server-side library.

Comment: ok, I will try rework on the app structure then... Thanks for your suggestion, really appreciate it!