# Angular type definition for `interval`

Tags: angular

I have an assignment like

```
this.timer4Updates = setInterval(() => {
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}, 150);
```

If I want to use Angular strict options I need to define the type of `timer4Updates`. According to what is suggested it should be `timer4Updates: NodeJS.Timeout`.

Which raises the next issue that for compile Angular complains

```
error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.
```

Searching for a solution I found that I need in the `tsconfig.json` something like

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
```

But even after setting it like this it won't work. Any idea how to solve it? Either by different definition of the variable or by some config parameters.

Comment: Reopen your IDE and try again

Comment: The error appears when I compile via CLI. So its not strictly related to the IDE. The Angular compiler has the problem.

Comment: On an unrelated note, forcing CD cycle to refresh every 150ms seems inelegant.

Comment: Does this the same issue?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315304/cannot-find-namespace-nodejs-when-using-nodejs-timer-in-ionic-2/47367655

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376589/typescript-what-type-is-f-e-setinterval (you can use window.setInterval, which is of type number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#return_value):

> The returned `intervalID` is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies
> the timer created by the call to `setInterval()`

So in TS, defining it as `number` should technically work.

```js
timer4Updates: number;

this.timer4Updates = setInterval(() => {
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}, 150);
```

On an unrelated note, forcing CD cycle to refresh every 150ms seems inelegant and inefficient.

Comment: Thx for the solution. I need to `detach` from the `cd` due to major performance issues. I have no other clue how to grant an update  beside doing it manually. But this is another issue. Thx.